# What's the best method for stripping undesirable html in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string-formatting

I'm making a fairly basic rails app and I was wondering what's the best way to strip undesirable html from text field (basically, all I'm looking to preserve are links and no more than 2 linebreaks).

Currently, I'm stripping all html and using simpleformat, since it seems to be less overhead than using RDiscount and Markdown/Textile, but this is not really an ideal solution.

Comment: I guess that you are talking about user input into a text field.

Comment: yes, should have put that in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is Sanitize gem.

http://wonko.com/post/sanitize

Comment: this seems like exactly what i was looking for, thanks.

Comment: how is this different/better than the Rails built in sanitizer? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/HTML/Sanitizer.html

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `sanitize` helper.

[Module
ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)